# Error: No instance for (Num Price) arising from the literal

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I'm praticing Haskell and I'm trying to create e movies store.

I created the types `Code`,`Name`,`Genre` and `Price`, a tuple `Movie` and a tuple list `Movies` and when I try add movies at `tableMovies` appear the message:

> ```
> Prelude> :l movies
> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( movies.hs, interpreted )
>
> movies.hs:11:45:
>     No instance for (Num Price) arising from the literal `50'
>     Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Price)
>     In the expression: 50
>     In the expression: (1, "Movie 1", "Adventure", 50)
>     In the expression:
>       [(1, "Movie 1", "Adventure", 50), (2, "Movie 2", "Horror", 30)]
> Failed, modules loaded: none.
> Prelude>
> ```

My code:

```
type Code = Integer
type Name = String
type Genre = String
data Price = Integer | Float

type Movie = (Code, Name, Genre,Price)

type Movies = [(Movie)]

tableMovies :: Movies
tableMovies = [ (001,"Movie 1", "Adventure",50)
             , (002,"Movie 2", "Horror", 30)]
```

I found some answers for this problem but I couldn't understand because the codes were very complexity to me. I'm only starting on Haskell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data Price = Integer | Float
```

This line creates three things: The type `Price`, and the constants `Integer` and `Float`. It works exactly like:

```
data Bool = False | True
```

In your case you have the new values `Integer` (of type `Price`) and `Float` (of type `Price`). These are unrelated to the *types* `Integer` and `Float`. And `50` is not a value of type `Price` (`Price` has only two possible values).

The whole thing is a bit confusing because types and values live in different namespaces. You can have a type called `X` and a value called `X` and they have nothing to do with each other (or in your case, a type called `Integer` and a value called `Integer`).

To create a type that contains either an integer or a float, you can do this:

```
data Price = PriceInteger Integer | PriceFloat Float
```

Now you can do `PriceInteger 50` and it will have type `Price` (but you still can't use a bare `50`). It's probably easier to just do `type Price = Integer` and not allow floats.

Answer (score 1):

`Float` and `Integer` are on the right hand side of your `data` declaration - you can view them as citizens of a different universe compared to types, as they are constructors, i.e. things that make a type.

If you want to have a sum type of `Integer` and `Float` you have to

```
data Price = I Integer | F Float deriving (Eq,Show)
```

But it would be best to represent monetary values as either `Rational` from `Data.Ratio` or `Scientific` from [`scientific`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific) and use the [`formatting`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/formatting) package to make string representations of fixed precision.

```
import Data.Ratio (Rational)
import Formatting

newtype Price = Price {getPrice :: Rational}
instance Show Price where
   show (Price p) = formatToString (fixed 2) p
```